# Manga where MC is transported into another world while in a school bus with others and has the power to control others

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

In the manga the MC is transported with the rest of his class while on a school bus. Then a person comes and tells them to survive or whatever and kills a student to make them behave, but a student was sleeping or something and was left out when they were checking status plates. A girl sees him and wakes him only to find a dragon is about to eat the school bus and them in it. He kills it and his classmates are three boys trying to do something against him and the girl, but he uses his power to control them (I mean they have to do anything he says, not take over their body).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for [Sokushi Cheat ga Saikyou Sugite, Isekai no Yatsura ga Marude Aite ni Naranai n desu ga](https://instant-death.fandom.com/wiki/Instant_Death_Wiki), or *The other world doesn't stand a chance against the power of instant death.*

The manga starts with a girl waking the sleeping main character, because a dragon is attacking their bus. He kills it by telling it to die. Then the girl explains what happened.  The class was transported to another world while on a school bus. A woman then appears and kills the teacher, not a student, when the teacher started asking questions. She then killed the bus driver because she was irritated her joke fell flat. She then has everyone check their status.  The main character, the girl, and a couple others were 'incompatible', so they received nothing.  The bus was then attacked after the powerful classmates left, circling back to her waking up the main character.  Afterwards three boys from their class came back to the bus. After one of them attacks the girl, the main character tells one of them to die, which kills the guy. The second boy goes to check on the first after the main character kills the first and tells those two not to move, so the main character tells him to die too.

The main differences are the person from the other world killed the teacher and the bus driver instead of a student, and the main character's power is not making people do what he says but to kill people instantly. He normally tells people to die when using the power, so it could be miss remembered as them doing what he tells them to. Especially since the third member of the boys who didn't die put a slave collar on himself and transferred ownership to the main character so the main character wouldn't kill him. He then did exactly what the main character told him to do.