# Isekai manga with a school bus having been transported to a different world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It starts with a school bus having been transported to a different world. Some students are told by a sage (?) that they have powers now, while some students do not have any powers. They then get attacked by a dragon.

The main character however was left behind because they couldn't sense any powers from him, but apparently he is "the end of all things personified" - death of everything given human form or something like that - basically he tells the opponent to die and they die. He travels with a fellow classmate who was told she has no powers. He is sort of looking after her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Manga where MC is transported into another world while in a school bus with others and has the power to control others](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231448/manga-where-mc-is-transported-into-another-world-while-in-a-school-bus-with-othe), *[Sokushi Cheat ga Saikyou Sugite, Isekai no Yatsura ga Marude Aite ni Naranai n desu ga](https://instant-death.fandom.com/wiki/Instant_Death_Wiki)*, or *The other world doesn't stand a chance against the power of instant death*.

[image: Image showing the main characters of the comic]

> The manga starts with a girl waking the sleeping main character, because a dragon is attacking their bus. He kills it by telling it to die. Then the girl explains what happened. The class was transported to another world while on a school bus. A woman then appears and kills the teacher, not a student, when the teacher started asking questions. She then killed the bus driver because she was irritated her joke fell flat. She then has everyone check their status. The main character, the girl, and a couple others were 'incompatible', so they received nothing. The bus was then attacked after the powerful classmates left, circling back to her waking up the main character. Afterwards three boys from their class came back to the bus. After one of them attacks the girl, the main character tells one of them to die, which kills the guy. The second boy goes to check on the first after the main character kills the first and tells those two not to move, so the main character tells him to die too.

Found with a search for `isekai schoolbus death powers`