# Isekai manga where the main character is the weakest among the students?

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking the title of this isekai manga, where a whole school bus (I think) full of students were suddenly transported into another world, and all of them were being analyzed and had their power capabilities estimated, or the specific amount of their power capabilities, one by one.

The main character's power is 2 (literally), while two of his girl friends got above average and higher amount of power and the two of them are the highest recorded among the students. All of his classmates and the other world people were laughing at him. The two girls who got the higher score did not like the actions of their classmates towards the MC.

Then other world people declared that he will become a slave because in their kingdom, the people who have the lowest amount of power recorded will become slaves or be disregarded by the people in the land, while the person who is above average or higher will be treated nicely. Because of his power and the weakest among the students.

Comment: Some similarities to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247219/isekai-manga-with-a-school-bus-having-been-transported-to-a-different-world?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Any specific abilities of the girl friends or the mc such as fire or water magic or super strength. Anything that stands out.

Comment: From the power measurement it reminds me of a certain sci-fi isekai but is this a medieval setting or is there any religions etc.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: there were no specific abilities, they only show what their how powerful they are.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is *Class Saiyasune de Urareta Ore wa, Jitsu wa Saikyou Parameter*, also known as, *I was Sold at the Lowest Price in my class, however, my Personal Parameter is the Most Powerful*

The manga starts with a class being transported to another world. they all have their power measured, with them having levels of in the thousands and ten thousands.  The main character goes last and has a power of 2. The classmates are auctioned off, with him as the last. after it is said that his power was 2, everyone laughed. There are then panels of his childhood friend and his love interest both being upset/annoyed at everyone laughing.

He is then shoved into a slave group of low power people, and they are kept in a room that has a door that can only be opened by people who more than 300 power. Meanwhile, his friends who had higher values are shown being treated well.

Comment: "they are kept in a room that has a door that can only be opened by people who less than 300 power" - Does it mean you can only open it if you're weak enough?

Comment: sorry, i was distracted when i wrote that. it should have been more instead of less.

Comment: thank you, I was looking for this and I hardly remember the title.